# Text for HTML Canvas not Showing on Screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I try to make text appear on my HTML canvas for this game that I am trying to develop, it doesn't appear. This is weird because for another similar project it just worked fine. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

It's not that scoreText is nonexistent, or the text is "", it has something to do with drawing it on the canvas.

```js
var gamePiece;
var droplets = [];
var score = 0;
var scoreText;

function startGame() {
  gamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
  scoreText = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 80, "text");
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = window.screen.width;
    this.canvas.height = window.screen.height - 100;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
      myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
    });
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.width / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;
  }
  this.crashWith = function(obj) {
    var myCenterX = this.x + (this.width / 2);
    var myCenterY = this.y + (this.height / 2);
    var oCenterX = obj.x + (obj.width / 2);
    var oCenterY = obj.y + (obj.height / 2);

    var crash = false;
    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(myCenterX - oCenterX, 2) + Math.pow(myCenterY - oCenterY, 2)) < this.width / 2 + obj.width / 2) {
      crash = true;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  var x, y;
  for (i = 0; i < droplets.length; i++) {
    if (gamePiece.crashWith(droplets[i])) {
      droplets.splice(i, 1);
      score++;
      console.log("crashed");
      break;
    }
  }

  myGameArea.clear();
  myGameArea.frameNo++;

  if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(20)) {
    wid = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    droplets.push(new component(25, 25, "blue", Math.random() * wid, -20));
  }

  for (i = 0; i < droplets.length; i++) {
    droplets[i].y += 5;
    droplets[i].update();
  }

  if (myGameArea.x && myGameArea.y) {
    gamePiece.x = myGameArea.x;
    gamePiece.y = myGameArea.y;
  }

  scoreText.text = "SCORE: " + score;
  console.clear();
  console.log(scoreText.text);
  scoreText.update();
  gamePiece.update();
}
startGame();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

It is supposed to display scoreText on the canvas, but it doesn't.

Comment: Any errors/warning on the Javascript console in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

*Typo / brainfart:* You never set the `type` of your component. The sixth argument you pass when initiating `scoreText` gets lost away and `if(this.type === 'text')` is never true.

```js
var gamePiece;
var droplets = [];
var score = 0;
var scoreText;

function startGame() {
  gamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
  scoreText = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 80, "text");
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = window.screen.width;
    this.canvas.height = window.screen.height - 100;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
      myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
    });
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
// here add the type argument
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type; // here set it to your component instance
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.width / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;
  }
  this.crashWith = function(obj) {
    var myCenterX = this.x + (this.width / 2);
    var myCenterY = this.y + (this.height / 2);
    var oCenterX = obj.x + (obj.width / 2);
    var oCenterY = obj.y + (obj.height / 2);

    var crash = false;
    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(myCenterX - oCenterX, 2) + Math.pow(myCenterY - oCenterY, 2)) < this.width / 2 + obj.width / 2) {
      crash = true;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  var x, y;
  for (i = 0; i < droplets.length; i++) {
    if (gamePiece.crashWith(droplets[i])) {
      droplets.splice(i, 1);
      score++;
      console.log("crashed");
      break;
    }
  }

  myGameArea.clear();
  myGameArea.frameNo++;

  if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(20)) {
    wid = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    droplets.push(new component(25, 25, "blue", Math.random() * wid, -20));
  }

  for (i = 0; i < droplets.length; i++) {
    droplets[i].y += 5;
    droplets[i].update();
  }

  if (myGameArea.x && myGameArea.y) {
    gamePiece.x = myGameArea.x;
    gamePiece.y = myGameArea.y;
  }

  scoreText.text = "SCORE: " + score;
  console.clear();
  console.log(scoreText.text);
  scoreText.update();
  gamePiece.update();
}
startGame();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```